# complier generating a mov back and forth on eax

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, x86-64, micro-optimization

```
int test1(int a, int b) {
    if (__builtin_expect(a < b, 0))
        return a / b;
    return b;
}
```

was compiled by clang with `-O3 -march=native` to

```
test1(int, int):                             # @test1(int, int)
        cmp     edi, esi
        jl      .LBB0_1
        mov     eax, esi
        ret
.LBB0_1:
        mov     eax, edi
        cdq
        idiv    esi
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     eax, esi  # moving eax back and forth
        ret
```

why `eax` is being moved back and forth after the `idiv` ?

gcc has a similar behavior so this seem to be intended.

gcc with `-O3 -march=native` complied the code to

```
test1(int, int):
        mov     r8d, esi
        cmp     edi, esi
        jl      .L4
        mov     eax, r8d
        ret
.L4:
        mov     eax, edi
        cdq
        idiv    esi
        mov     r8d, eax
        mov     eax, r8d  #back and forth mov
        ret
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/lTlvqn)

Comment: I don't think this is intended. It seems that the `expect` confuses both compilers.

Comment: @geza i find it unlikely that both complier have the same issue

Comment: If you remove the expect, you can see where the extra move comes from.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete solution to the puzzle but should give some clues.

Without the `__builtin_expect`, clang generates:

```
test2(int, int):                             # @test2(int, int)
        mov     ecx, esi
        cmp     edi, esi
        jge     .LBB1_2
        mov     eax, edi
        cdq
        idiv    ecx
        mov     ecx, eax
.LBB1_2:
        mov     eax, ecx
        ret
```

While the register allocation is still weird here, it at least makes sense: if the branch is taken, the value of `b` in `ecx` is transfered to `eax` as the return value.  If it is not taken, the result of the division (in `eax`) has to be transferred to `ecx` to be in the same register as in the other case.

It could be that a `__builtin_expect` convinces the compiler to special case the case where the branch is taken late in the compilatin process, orphaning the `.LBB1_2` label and causing it to be ultimately absent from the assembly.

Comment: Interesting, maybe at one point there was a basic-block boundary between those instructions.  Clang's output puts comments on basic-block boundaries that aren't branch targets, like `# %bb.2:`, but if this hypothesis is correct, that determination must happen after this missed-optimization is set in stone.  We do *not* see a `% bb` comment between the mov instructions, so at least by final asm output time clang knows it's not a BB boundary.

Comment: @PeterCordes If you turn off label filtering, the orphan label is actually there.

Comment: Adding a `volatile int i=0;`  before the `return b;` avoids this missed optimization for both gcc and clang (at the cost of a store to the red-zone, so you don't actually want this).  But it doesn't change the overall function layout.  https://godbolt.org/z/Fw1UOC

Answer (score 1):

`idiv esi` is 32-bit operand-size, so EAX is already zero-extended to fill RAX.  Therefore copying to ESI or R8D and back has no effect on the value in EAX.  (And the calling convention doesn't require zero-extension or sign-extension to 64-bit anyway; 32-bit types are returned in 32-bit registers with possible garbage in the upper 32.)

**This looks like purely a missed optimization.  (There's no microarchitectural performance reason that this would be a good thing either.)**

Comment: Interestingly, if the branch is not in the code, the compiler does not emit any moves.  See my answer for an idea how the compiler could have gotten this idea.